# Какой тайпкаст использовать?

Tags: php

Есть ли разница между `(string)` и `strval()`? Между `(int)` и `intval()`? Между `(bool)` и `boolval()`? Просто сейчас какой-то плагин в Шторме показывает что лучше использовать нативный каст, а не функцию - типа он быстрее, но у меня такое смутное воспоминание что я когда-то видел что они по разному работают в некоторых случаях...

Comment: Нет никакой разницы.

Comment: @u_mulder и работают одинаково и по производительности?

Comment: Ну тебе же шторм пишет что `(type)` работает быстрее чем функция, так как нет оверхеда на вызов функции.